# Alternative symbol to # for URL with pushState?

Tags: url, hex

I'm curious as to the best way to use the relatively new pushState feature for URL's.

From what I understand, a hex "#" symbol is typically used:

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/page.html#someoperation
```

However, in browsers such as Safari, two "#" symbols cannot be used. This is an issue if you wish to store some data in the URL.

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/page.html#someoperation#somedata=data
```

...Because it converts the second hex to a "%23".

I also understand that certain characters are "reserved" although I am unsure what this really means, and the "#" is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` delimits a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) which is why browsers may refuse to accept that character twice.  Read [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and its successor [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) for the full list of unsafe and reserved characters, there's quite a lot of them.